# select where condition if exists else other condition limit X

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to get a SQL query in Postgres where I could get 5 results based on a standard query :

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT 5;
```

But if I get less than 5 results I'd like to change the WHERE condition, but keeping a total of 5 results (1st condition + 2nd condition).

Would you have any clue how to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UNION ALL (or UNION if it suits your requirement) and order by a dummy number column created specifically to set the priority of the rows:

```
select 1 nr, col1, col2, ... from tablename where condition1
union all
select 2 nr, col1, col2, ... from tablename where condition2
union all
select 3 nr, col1, col2, ... from tablename where condition3
union all
  ............................
order by nr
limit 5
```

Comment: Ok thanks it does answer my problem!
Otherwise, I'm found a way creating a plpgsql function with IF using COUNT but your solution is much simpler.